# Why is setInterval making infinite loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, setinterval

I'm trying to set a timer so it display the seconds and min left of an user and I'm using `setInterval` to get the seconds and if there are 60 seconds it will reduce 1 min from the user.
The thing is that I'm getting infinite `for` loops every time I try to do it.

Something like

```
var userObj = {
    name: "",
    min: 0,
    sec:0
}

function timerCount() {
    while (userObj.sec !== 0) {
        console.log(userObj.min)
        if (userObj.sec == 0) {
            setInterval(function() {
                userObj.min--;
                userObj.sec = 59     
            }, 1000);
        }
        while(userObj.sec !== 0) {
            setInterval(function() {
                console.log(userObj.sec)
                userObj.sec--;  
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to store `setInterval()` in a variable and `clearInterval(variable)` to stop it, else it will call infinitely

Comment: Javascript in a browser or in node.js is an event driven language and is single threaded so you cannot loop in a `while()` loop and expect ANY other timer code to execute.  The timer callback will never execute until you finish your `while()` loop.  So, you can't loop like this waiting for a timer to update something.  The timer will never get to execute so you'll just have an infinite loop.

Comment: There are at least a couple of problems here.  1) You're calling setInterval() in a while loop.  setInterval() sets the callback to be called repeatedly (every 1000 ms in your case).  But you're calling setInterval() within a while loop, so you're setting up multiple intervals all executing in parallel.  2) The callback functions in the setInterval() are called asyncronously with the rest of the code.  So you can't modify userObj.sec in the callback and see them affect your while loop the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userObj = {
    name: "",
    min: 0,
    sec:5
}

function timerCount() {

  if(userObj.min === 0 && userObj.sec === 0) {
    return;
  }

  if (userObj.sec === 0) {
    userObj.min--;
      userObj.sec = 59     
    }     
  userObj.sec--;  


  setTimeout(timerCount, 1000)
}

timerCount()
```

With little effort we can remove those while loops that are causing the issue.  We also want to check for the minutes and seconds equalling 0 so we know when to end our timer.

Answer (score 0):

You put your setInterval inside a loop (and other things).

No need to separate time in minutes and seconds, just work with seconds and do some math.

Here is a code that works:

```
var userObj = {
    name: "Joe",
    sec: 3605
}

function timerCount()
{
    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        console.log(getTimeLeft(userObj.sec));
        userObj.sec--;
        if(userObj.sec == 0)
        {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log('NO MORE TIME');
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function getTimeLeft(sec)
{
    var seconds = Math.floor( sec % 60 );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (sec / 60) % 60 );
    var hours = Math.floor( (sec / 60 / 60) );

    return {
        'hours' : hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    }
}

timerCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one more approach you could think of:

```
function timer(min, sec){   
    if (min === 0 && sec === 0) return;

    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(min, sec);

       if (min > 0 && sec === 0) timer(min-1, 59);
       if (sec > 0) timer(min, sec-1);  
    }, 1000);
 }
```

You can invoke this timer:

```
timer(userObj.min, 0)
```