# Javascript clock / timer breaks

Tags: javascript

I am planning to build multiple timer.  I started by building a simple clock using the following code.

the issue is, the clock will run for a few minute and the website will break, I think it's due to running out of memory.

when I console.log the output. It appears the command is ran more than once per second. The counter for the console.log line will say 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 etc etc. quickly doubling into some astronomical number. and the site will become non responsive in a few minute.

Is it an efficiency issue with the code? 
Or it is just not feasible to use java script to up date something every second.
because I am planning on making multiple timer on the same page. (maybe around 5-10)

I tried this on google chrome.

```
updateTime();
    function updateTime() {
        var d = new Date;
        var hours = d.getHours();
        var mins = d.getMinutes();
        var secs = d.getSeconds();
        var ampm = 'AM';
        if (hours >= 12) {
            ampm = 'PM';
        }
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours = hours - 12;
        }
        formatted_time = hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs + ampm;
        //console.log(formatted_time);
        $("#currenttime").html(formatted_time);
        window.setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: You're setting an interval, that means it will do it repeatedly, and you make a new interval every loop, before long you've got millions of intervals all running, change that to setTimeout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is setInterval making infinite loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200897/why-is-setinterval-making-infinite-loops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running out of memory because each new setInterval call starts a periodic function.

So each time updateTime is called, a new one is started. That means 1 call, 2 calls, 4 ... 2^n. (after 60 seconds you will have 2^60 calls. This is a 18 digit decimal number).Calls in just n seconds. You probably meant to use setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

Set a `setInterval` inside the function that means `setInterval` will run in each time you call a function And while you call the function with `window.setInterval(updateTime, 1000);` it will not call just the part of update time it will run the `setInterval` part as well again and again .. so you can use it like...

```js
function updateTime() {
    var updateIt = function(){
       var d = new Date;
       var hours = d.getHours();
       var mins = d.getMinutes();
       var secs = d.getSeconds();
       var ampm = 'AM';
       if (hours >= 12) {
          ampm = 'PM';
       }
       if (hours > 12) {
         hours = hours - 12;
       }
       formatted_time = hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs + ampm;
       console.log(formatted_time);
       $("#currenttime").html(formatted_time);
  }
  setInterval(updateIt, 1000);
}
updateTime();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="currenttime"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right,  running out of memory will cause your browser to crush. Try this and see if it stops crashing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Time</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // This function gets the current time and injects it into the DOM
            function updateClock() {
                // Gets the current time
                var now = new Date();

                // Get the hours, minutes and seconds from the current time
                var hours = now.getHours();
                var minutes = now.getMinutes();
                var seconds = now.getSeconds();

                // Format hours, minutes and seconds
                if (hours < 10) {
                    hours = "0" + hours;
                }
                if (minutes < 10) {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }

                // Gets the element we want to inject the clock into
                var elem = document.getElementById('clock');

                // Sets the elements inner HTML value to our clock data
                elem.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <!--
        This is the key to making the clock function.
        When the page loads, it calls the javascript function "setInterval()",
        which will call our function "updateClock()" once every 200 milliseconds.
    -->
    <body onload="setInterval('updateClock()', 200);">
        <!-- This is the container for our clock, it can be any HTML element. -->
        <h1 id="clock"></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

if it does, take a look here http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Why not `onload="setInterval(updateClock, 200)"`? Then you don't need to be interpreting a string as code...