# setInterval timer function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm making a countdown timer. When I take out the setInterval() function, and decrement the time without pausing, the program works correctly.

But when I use the setInterval() function to call the code that decrements my time only every second, the program hangs.

```
function timeControl() {
   var minutesLeft = $('#minutes').text();
   var secondsLeft = $('#seconds').text();

    while(Number(minutesLeft) > 0 || Number(secondsLeft) > 0) {
        window.setInterval(decreaseTime, 1000);

        minutesLeft = $('#minutes').text();
        secondsLeft = $('#seconds').text();
    }
 }


function decreaseTime() {
   var secondsLeft = $('#seconds').text();
   var minutesLeft = $('#minutes').text();
   if((Number(minutesLeft) > 0) && (Number(secondsLeft) == 0)) {
     $('#minutes').text(Number(minutesLeft) - 1);
     $('#seconds').text(4);
    } else {
       $('#seconds').text(Number(secondsLeft) - 1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: `setInterval` is asynchronous, so your code is not updating the elements, so you've got an infinite loop.

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to use `setInterval()`. Don't have a `while` loop with a dependency on something that's scheduled, it will never terminate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is setInterval making infinite loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200897/why-is-setinterval-making-infinite-loops)

Answer (score 2):

You add `while` and it looping very fast, so you `setInterval()` calling many times, so browser hanging. You don't need to while, because `setInterval` run every time that defined in `setInterval` second parameter. You can use following code:

```
var decreaseTimeInterval;
function timeControl() {
    decreaseTimeInterval = window.setInterval(decreaseTime, 1000);
}

function decreaseTime() {
    var secondsLeft = $('#seconds').text();
    var minutesLeft = $('#minutes').text();
    if((Number(minutesLeft) > 0) && (Number(secondsLeft) == 0)) {
        $('#minutes').text(Number(minutesLeft) - 1);
        $('#seconds').text(4);
    } else if(Number(minutesLeft) == 0 && Number(secondsLeft) == 0) { //end of script
        clearInterval(decreaseTimeInterval); //clear interval to prevent do again
    } else {
        $('#seconds').text(Number(secondsLeft) - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be conflating the asynchronous `setInterval` function with a synchronous `sleep` kind of function.  They are totally different.  The `setInterval` function sets a timer for you.  It says, "run function x every y milliseconds".  But here, you are setting that function umpteen different times in that while loop.  Essentially, you start setting off more and more timers, hundreds or thousands of them, each one running the `decreaseTime` function every 1 second, until the program hangs.

What you want to do is put the `setInterval` function at the top level of your program, and have it run the `timeControl` function every 1000 ms.  Remove the while loop from the `timeControl` function -- you don't need it since the `setInterval` function itself is running a loop for you.  However, you will need to save the return value of `setInterval` in a variable so that you can clear it when your stop condition is reached.  In short, read more about `setInterval`: it's a totally different concept from `sleep`.